# Get loaded CSS between 2 divs as stylesheet.css

Tags: css, code-snippets

I'm trying to get a specific generated CSS for an area on one of my sites to use this CSS on the homepage from one of my sites.

I used all types of soft and FF add-ons to get the complete CSS for that specific area. However, they do not combine the CSS as 1.
I still have to copy/paste and have a chance of getting duplicate-loaded CSS.

My hope is that there exists a code snippet that reads the CSS between 2 `div`s and generate a .css file on the fly so I can use the generated CSS in another project.
(The reason I ask this is because there are over 4000 lines of CSS loaded from different CSS files.)

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect an element (right click on it, "Inspect Element") in [Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome) there's a styles window on the right, underneath that is **Computed Style**, this includes everything non-standard about that element including all ancestors properties that made it that way.

Using the styles listed under there, you can get everything together that made the style you're seeing.

Comment: +1 lovely. This is something Firebug doesn't do. Remember to check the "Show inherited" box if you need the full definition.

Comment: @Pekka - I so wish I could have my firebug and my chrome together though :'(

Comment: @nick , this is almost the same what i get when i use firebug for FF.
Then again , if i go tru the called style classes , i get the chance i load duplicated css.
There's also no reason to load padding-bottom: 0px;
padding-left: 0px;
padding-right: 0px;
padding-top: 0px;
Also it do it only for a single div and not for the class elements between it.

Comment: @osc2nuke - The "class elements between" could be all duplicates...so a bit on a conundrum there.  In "Computed Style" you just want the bold ones, everything else is default for that element type, taking only the bold doesn't work?

Comment: @Nick , i truely thank you for trying to help.
However , it isnt how i wantit , i dont want to go true all classes between them manualy , i want to have it fully generated , not click each element one by one and copy/paste test-drive.